# collection to be generated from all the sub-folders into one

Tags: collections, docpad

How to create a collection to be generated from all the sub-folders into one.

For example:

```
/src/article/2011/
            /2012/
            /2013/
```

=>

```
/out/article/
```

The usual way of sub-folders does not take:

```
posts: (database) ->
    database.findAll({relativeOutDirPath:'posts'},[date:-1])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get all the documents inside sub-directories of the article directory, like `/article/2011/post.html`, you could use:

`insideSubfolder: (database) ->
    database.findAll({relativeOutDirPath:/article[\/\\]\w+/},[date:-1])`

If you also want to accept documents inside article, like `/article/index.html`, you could use:

`insideSubfolder: (database) ->
    database.findAll({relativeOutDirPath:/article/},[date:-1])`

If you want say `src/documents/article/2011/post.html` to be outputted to `out/article/post.html` please say so in a comment and I'll figure out what is needed. Thanks.

Comment: If you want say src/documents/article/2011/post.html to be outputted to out/article/post.html please say so in a comment and I'll figure out what is needed. Thanks. - 

Can you suggest how to do this? :-)

Comment: @npofopr try setting the `outPath` meta data manually in your file to where you want it to go.